# How do I respawn the Ender Dragon when not running a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When my brother and I were playing on LAN for one of my worlds we defeated the ender dragon and wanted to refight it. I looked at a few online helps but they only tell me how to do it on a server.

Comment: You could use [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) or the /summon command (1.7+ only)

Comment: If you are running a local or online server you can just replace your "The End" folder and whenever you create another Ender Portal, you will get a new "The End" world.

Comment: Respawning the ender dragon works exactly the same way on singleplayer as on a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LAN worlds are considered to have cheats enabled, at least for the host.

```
/summon EnderDragon
```

is the command you're looking for.

Comment: do I have to use it in the end? And will it re-bring about the end escape portal/the philosophy thing?

Comment: I would certainly do it in the end. You CAN summon an Ender Dragon in the overworld/nether, but because of their ability to remove any normal block type, it can make quite the mess. As for your other question, AFAIK Ender Dragons spawn a portal when they die, regardless of how many Ender Dragons there have been. The portal blocks themselves trigger the game over 'poem.' TL;DR: No, Yes.

Answer (score 1):

In the Snapshot 15w44a, you can re-summon the enderdragon by placing end-crystals on the edges of the portal in the end. This will maybe change (its just a snapshot version), but this should be the intended way of fighting against the enderdragon again and again in survival without any commands/cheats. See the changelog [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/3qklhj/snapshot_15w44a_is_out_now_with_a_proper_way_to/).